# Long actions with continuous

Tags: future-constructions

1 When I was little I went to school

2 When I was little I was going to school

My friend who's a native told me that when I state general information about my childhood 1 is idiomatic and 2 could indicate some temporary action or may be used used in a different context like " when I was little I was going to school, suddenly I felt tired and fainted. Do you agree with that? What bother me is that I gave her one more question.

3 When I'm old I will plant plants

4 When I'm old I will be planting plants

And here she said thay both have the same meaning and are idomatic. As a learner I'd say 3 is idiomatic and 4 is odd? What do think are both fine and why?

Comment: Please do not ask more than one question at a time.

Comment: I know sorry . I had to do it to explain my way of thinking.

Comment: was going and will be planting have nothing in common at all.

Comment: I wanted to show that these 4 examples about the past and future are similar but my friend gave me different explenation.

Comment: They all mean different things.

Comment: Talking about 'planting plants' is not idiomatic; you would say something like "When I am old I will spend my time gardening".